# Bad argument error while drawing border

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to draw border along with the image , I got good help from [opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/copyMakeBorder/copyMakeBorder.html) and also syntax from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=copymakeborder#copymakeborder) and it work fine , i tried it in with this value

```
copyMakeBorder( src, dst, top, bottom, left, right, bordertype , Scalar(0,255,0) );
```

it works but when i try to use [borderinterpolation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=copymakeborder#int%20borderInterpolate%28int%20p,%20int%20len,%20int%20borderType%29) to make borders constant like

```
int borderInterpolate = (50, 100, BORDER_TRANSPARENT);
copyMakeBorder( src, dst, top, bottom, left, right, borderInterpolate , Scalar(0,255,0) );
```

it show me runtime error of

```
Bad argument (Unknown/Unsupportive border type)
```

and how to achieve this 3rd result also given in the documentation

[image]

Comment: I've answered your question as asked, but I suspect you need to add some more details to describe exactly what you are looking for. The code you posted has nothing to do with the `borderInterpolate()` function you linked to.

Comment: Perhaps edit your question to clarify that you are trying to draw a transparent border. Also, in the future, please only post one question per question. The tutorial even says that the 3rd result is from using `BORDER_REPLICATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the relevant documentation for [`borderInterpolate()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?#borderinterpolate), which is referenced in the documentation for `copyMakeBorder()` (emphasis mine):

> Border type, one of the BORDER_* , **except for BORDER_TRANSPARENT** and BORDER_ISOLATED

This explains the error you are getting -- `BORDER_TRANSPARENT` is not supported by `copyMakeBorder()`

Even though the `BORDER_TRANSPARENT` flag is not supported, there is still a way to create transparent borders. You can use the `BORDER_CONSTANT` flag when calling `copyMakeBorder` on a BGRA image, as long as your constant value has a zero 4th channel value. A simple example follows:

```
const auto im = cv::imread("some_image.jpg");
cv::cvtColor(im, im, CV_BGR2BGRA); // Image must have alpha channel!

// clone() below is important -- there is a bug if using ROI without cloning first.
const auto roi = im(cv::Rect(200,200,200,200)).clone();
cv::Mat bordered;
cv::copyMakeBorder(roi, bordered, 20, 20, 20, 20, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar::all(0));
```

As an aside, I don't know what your intent was in your assignment to `borderInterpolate`, but due to C++'s comma operator, the line you wrote:

```
int borderInterpolate = (50, 100, BORDER_TRANSPARENT);
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
int borderInterpolate = BORDER_TRANSPARENT; // 50 and 100 are evaluated and ignored
```

Comment: i am trying to draw transparent border like the 3rd one image in the documentation

Comment: your code is not making the border like 3rd image have

Comment: That's correct. Your last comment (before edits) asked about making a transparent border, which is what I answered. Did you read my second comment on your question? I told you which flag to use there.